# Difference between layoutSubviews() and viewWillLayoutSubviews()

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I understand that `layoutSubviews()` is a method in `UIView` and `viewWillLayoutSubviews()` is a method in `UIViewController`, they are both used to adjust the position of the subviews when the bounds/frame changes, but I'm not exactly sure the difference between them and when to use them. Could someone please enlighten me?

Comment: They are not "both used" for anything. They are messages letting you know something is happening. Whether you respond to that information is up to you.

Answer (score 16):

There is no effective difference. One (`layoutSubviews`) is a message the runtime sends to the view, the other (`viewWillLayoutSubviews`) is a message the runtime sends to the view controller. The message to the view controller tells the view controller that its view is about to receive the view message! That's all. They go together.

Answer (score 6):

`viewWillLayoutSubviews` is called when view controller's view's bounds changed (usually happens when view loaded, or orientation changed, or if it's a child view controller, and its view was changed by the parent view controller), but before it's subview's bounds or position changes. You can override this method to make some changes to subview's bounds or position before the view layouts them.

`layoutSubviews`, from Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622482-layoutsubviews):

> You should override this method only if the autoresizing and constraint-based behaviors of the subviews do not offer the behavior you want

This method gets called when a layout update happens, either by changing the view's bounds explicitly or call `setNeedsLayout` or `layoutIfNeeded` on the view to force a layout update. Please remember that it will be called automatically by the OS, and you should never call it directly. It's quite rare that you need to override this method, cause usually the autoresizing or constraint will do the job for you.

Answer (score -1):

You can call the `layoutSubviews()` of UIView when you are changing any constraint value which is inside the UIView and more then one element is effected by the constraint change. When you are performing some task by changing the constraint by taking an outlet of the constraint at runtime you can call this. But this is not a best practice. I suggest call `layoutIfNeeded()` instead of this `layoutSubviews()`.

You need to use `viewWillLayoutSubviews()` function when you want to perform some task just before any element changes its size or position in the view controller.

When you are going to make an application, those 2 functions are rarely used in worst case scenarios. This is as per my understanding. Thanks.

Comment: From Apple's [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622482-layoutsubviews), you should not directly call `layoutSubviews()`

Comment: great, that means what i was thinking is correct. i haven't seen that actually before but i was thinking that this function should not be called.

Comment: "You need to call" No. Never call it.

Comment: if i should NOT directly call layoutSubviews(), can I still subclass UIView, override the superclass implementation of layoutSubviews() and call the super.layoutSubviews() from the subclass layoutSubviews()? Like is it legal to do this? Is it something ok to do?

Comment: in the sub class if you want to perform something and thats related to layout where you are using the updated frame of the UIView, then you can use like you said.

Comment: Unless you are subclassing UIView and doing your own layout, you should never call `layoutSubviews` or `layoutIfNeed` directly. Call `setNeedsLayout` if the layout needs to be updated.